# Sending SMS using Nexmo.Csharp.Client

Tags: c#, vonage

After running my code as I have seen in the documentation

```
var creds = new Nexmo.Api.Request.Credentials
        {
            ApiKey = "xxxxxx",
            ApiSecret = "xxxxxxxxx"
        };

        //this var Im getting the error
        var results = SMS.Send(new SMS.SMSRequest
        {
            from = "CLient",
            to = "639xxxxxxx",
            text = "this is a test"
        }, creds);
```

And this is the error says

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Some guys are trying to down vote and not try to post a comment whats the problem.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: Well maybe this errors occurs in Nexmo becuase the error is part of the dependencies of nexmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that might help here. In the docs, check the "Install your dependencies" section and check that the Nexmo client has installed OK.

I'd also recommend taking a look at the full script and making sure you have the imports etc - that error message could indicate a missing dependency. Here's the link to the runnable code that the docs page uses:

- Code: https://github.com/nexmo/nexmo-dotnet-code-snippets/blob/master/NexmoDotnetCodeSnippets/Authentication/BasicAuth.cs#L17-L21
- Documentation: https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/code-snippets/send-an-sms/dotnet

Comment: Its a bug in nexmo i think I lower down the version of nexmo and itworks.

Comment: I think we had some issues with the way we were updating nuget but lowering the version would also work!